# Writing a webserver in C

Tags: c, http, webserver

I am trying to write a simple Webserver in C.  As of now I can receive connections and receive messages in full.  However, in accordance with the HTTP/1.0 protocol, I want to be able to send information back to the client when the "\r\n\r\n" sequence is encountered.  However, when using Telnet to test my server, when I enter "\r\n\r\n", the server does nothing until I hit "^]" on the client.  I tested this against Apache and Apache does not have this problem.  So I was hoping to some information on how to mimic the Apache behavior.  My code is added below but please keep in mind I am no where near done nor have I implemented a lot of error checking.
Thanks!

```
main(){
        int sock_fd = 0;
        int client_fd = 0;
        struct sockaddr_in socket_struct;
        /*Creates the socket*/
        if ((sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", getprogname(), strerror(errno));
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }/*Ends the socket creation*/

        /*Populates the socket address structure*/
        socket_struct.sin_family = AF_INET;
        socket_struct.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
        socket_struct.sin_port =htons(port);

        if (bind(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr*) &socket_struct, sizeof(socket_struct)) < 0)
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", getprogname(), strerror(errno));
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }//Ends the binding.

        if (listen(sock_fd, 5) <0)
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", getprogname(), strerror(errno));
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }//Ends the listening function

        if ( (client_fd = accept(sock_fd, NULL, NULL)) <0)
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", getprogname(), strerror(errno));
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }//Ends the accepting.
        while ( (size = read(client_fd, msg, 1024)) > 0)
        {
                //size = recv(client_fd, msg, 1024, MSG_PEEK|MSG_WAITALL);
                if ( (msg[size-4] == 13) && (msg[size-3] == 10)&&(msg[size-2] == 13) && (msg[size-1] == 10) )
                {
                        char* buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof("The msg was: ")+ sizeof(msg));
                        sprintf(buffer, "The msg was: %s", msg);
                        send(client_fd, buffer, sizeof("The msg was: ")+ sizeof(msg), MSG_OOB);
                }

        }//ends the while loop for receiving data
        close(client_fd);
}
```

Comment: try to do a `printf()` and see if it enters the `if()` condition inside the `while` loop. Seems like there is a problem @ `send()`

Comment: Its not a problem with send because I already did the printf() thing before posting...thanks though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this line won't work:

```
while ( (size = read(client_fd, msg, 1024)) > 0)
```

This will receive chunks of messages, and every chunk you receive will overwrite the last chunk.  Do something like this:

```
char msg[1024];
size_t pos = 0;
while (1) {
    assert(pos < sizeof(msg));
    ssize_t amt = read(client_fd, msg + pos, sizeof(msg) - pos);
    if (amt < 0)
        err(1, "read failed");
    if (amt == 0)
        break; // EOF
    pos += amt;
    char *e = strstr(msg, "\r\n\r\n");
    if (e) {
        size_t msglen = e - msg;
        /* Handle a complete message here */
    }
}
```

This way, as you receive chunks of the message, they get written into your buffer.  Once you have the `"\r\n\r\n"` sequence, then you can deal with the whole message, even though you might get it in chunks.

**Key lesson:** In TCP, packet boundaries and message boundaries might be completely different, and the sizes you get from `read` might be different still.  You have to find the end of a message by looking at the data itself, not by looking at how much data is returned from `read()` (except for EOF, which is signaled when `read()` returns 0).

**Footnote:** I don't think out-of-band data does what you think it does.

```
send(client_fd, buffer, sizeof("The msg was: ")+ sizeof(msg), MSG_OOB);
```

Out-of-band data is a quirky feature of TCP that should almost certainly be avoided in modern protocols.  Its implementation differs from platform to platform in such a way that it is only safe to send *one byte* of out-of-band data.

It is used for some things by the Telnet protocol (and by extension, FTP, which is built on Telnet), but has no purpose in HTTP.

Comment: Thank you for the help!  I changed it to work with recv instead of read but you definitely put me on the right track so thank you so much for that

Comment: @tpar44: For sockets, `recv` and `read` are the same (except for the flags parameter) so feel free to use either one.